# How can I show that the dimension of span is . . .?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The Krylov subspace generated by $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ is defined by :

$K_k(A,x)=span\{x,Ax,A^2x,...,A^{k-1}x\}$

How do I show its dimension is at most $k$?

I only know that $dim(span (V))=rank (W)$, where $V$ is a set of column vectors and $W$ is a matrix created by collecting all vectors in $V$.
But then I'm not sure how to use this fact.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If all vectors are linearly independent, then the span has dimension $k$, otherwise less. So it is obvious.

Comment: The set has exaclty $k$ vectors, so the rank cat not exceed $k$.

Comment: Ah such simple detail. Thanks everyone guess I'm not paying attention about the definition.

Comment: @uranix: the set has *at most* $\,k$ vectors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** You have $k$ vectors, then if all of them are l.i, the dimension will be $k$, if at least one of them l.d with another, the dimension will be $<k$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** there are only $k$ vectors in your list, so only $k$ columns in your matrix. What does that tell you about the rank?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the span of any $k$ vectors has dimension at most $k$.